# How to inhibit selection of TK Text widget?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, textselection

I am trying to find the best way to inhibit text selection in a Tk text widget.
Here an example of code using Iwidget's ScrolledText:

```
package require Iwidgets
iwidgets::scrolledtext .t 
pack .t
```

I already tried to bind to `<<Selection>>` virtual event without success yet to unbind `<Double-1>` event.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It's moderately awkward to prevent the selection from being created (there are a great many bindings that do things with it) but you *can* easily prevent it from affecting the rest of the application (by configuring the text widget to have `-exportselection false`). Then all you need to do is ensure that it can't be seen by configuring it to be invisible (through the text widget's `-selectbackground` and `-selectborderwidth` options).

Comment: Also, you were probably having problems with `<Double-1>` because it is applied using a widget class binding and there are other related bindings that also have an effect. Too hard to sort all that lot out!

Comment: Is there a way to disable selection or change selection color to a disabled text width? If it is disabled, the -selectbackground won't work.